# Why does Python see my variable as an attribute?

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes

**Technical context** In a derived class I want to use a subset of a list in my super class and store it in a variable.

**Business context**: I run a simulation for curing patients from viruses with drugs. To find out what happens with patients not consequently following their drug prescriptions, I want to select at random some of the prescribed drugs and apply only these. So I use the following names:

- `TreatedPatient` parent class of patients taking all their medicines
- `NonCompliantPatient` class of patients that don't
- `maxPop` maximal virus population the patient can contain
- `takeProb` probability a patient takes a prescribed medicine
- `TreatedPatient.getPrescriptions()` function returning the list of prescribed drugs
- `activeDrugs` variable to contain the drugs actually taken

**My code**

```
class NonCompliantPatient(TreatedPatient):
    def __init__(self, viruses, maxPop, takeProb):
        super(TreatedPatient, self).__init__(viruses, maxPop)
        self.takeProb = takeProb

    def update(self):
        # Which drugs are actually taken?
        activeDrugs = [drug for drug in self.getPrescriptions() 
                       if random.random() < self.takeProb]
```

**Misterious error message**

```
C:\Knowledge\Python\ps4.py in update(self)
     13     def update(self):
     14         # Which drugs are actually taken?
---> 15         activeDrugs = [drug for drug in self.getPrescriptions() if random.random() < self.takeProb]
     16 
     17         # Which viruses survive?

C:\Knowledge\Python\ps3b.pyc in getPrescriptions(self)

AttributeError: 'NonCompliantPatient' object has no attribute 'activeDrugs'
```

**Please explain why `activeDrugs` is seen as an attribute**

Comment: Without seeing `getPrescriptions` and `TreatedPatient`, I don't know how we can answer this.

Comment: _C:\Knowledge\Python\ps3b.pyc in getPrescriptions(self)_ ... the problem is in `getPrescriptions`.

Comment: `self.activeDrugs` makes it an instance variable, your `activeDrugs` is local to the update method.

Comment: please show what `getPrescription` method looks like

Comment: Sorry, TreatedPatient comes from a precompiled python file. But meanwhile I found a solution. Only, I don't know why it solves the problem.